# If statement in Shortcode to display different content based of Atts

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

So i have a shortcode called [`kerrigan`] and I want to have 3 atts where when used each one will display different content for the shortcode so for example [`kerrigan link="true"`] it shows a certain return, when I use [`kerrigan icon="true"`] it shows a different return same for [`kerrigan image="true"`] than I would like to have just [`kerrigan`] have it's own content to return also. So pretty much have it output something different depending on what I put in there as the atts

```
add_shortcode('kerrigan', 'kerring');
function kerrigan( $atts, $content = null )
{
array(
    'link'  => 'true',
    'icon'  => 'true',
    'image' => 'true',
    );

if($link == 'true'){
    return 'display content 1';
}

if($icon == 'true'){
    return 'display content 2';
}

if($image == 'true'){
    return 'display content 3';
}

}
```

I'm still learning PHP so my if statment syntax I"m sure are a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($link = 'true'){

}
```

should be

```
if($link == 'true'){
}
```

And so on for others !!

```
= is for assignment 

== is for comarison.
```

Comment: Thank you, although is that all that needs to be done for everything to work?

Comment: well it depends on the logic on how u want to perform the operation. But adding == will fix your comparison logic.

Comment: When I try this now it just shows everything from the first return.

Comment: could u explain a bit what u are trying to do since the array is defined inside the function and hence first statement will be true each time and will return from there always !!

Comment: I would like if I use the shortcode [kerrigan icon="true"] to display only the content that I have in the return for the $icon if statement. And if i use [kerrigan image="true"] to display only the content I have for the $image if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
function kerring($atts)
{
    if(is_array($atts)){
        foreach($atts as $key=>$value){
            switch ($key){
                case 'link': if($value == 'true') return 'content for link';
                case 'icon': if($value == 'true') return 'content for icon';
                case 'image': if($value == 'true') return 'content for image';
                default: return 'some default content for other atts';
            }
        }
    }
    return 'content without atts';
}

add_shortcode('kerrigan', 'kerring');
```

added array check, it works, but i think its a misuse of `foreach` statement, another aproach would be extracting `$atts` as variables

```
function kerring($atts)
{
    extract($atts);

    if(isset($link)){
        if($link=='true'){
            return 'content for link';
        }
    }

    if(isset($icon)){
        if($icon=='true'){
            return 'content for icon';
        }
    }

    if(isset($image)){
        if($image=='true'){
            return 'content for image';
        }
    }

    return 'content without atts';
}

add_shortcode('kerrigan', 'kerring');
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working although when I save a post I get the warning Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/storm/public_html/wp-content/themes/stormable/functions/shortcodes.php on line 437

Comment: Also these two Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/storm/public_html/wp-content/themes/stormable/functions/shortcodes.php:437) in /home/storm/public_html/wp-admin/post.php on line 233

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/storm/public_html/wp-content/themes/stormable/functions/shortcodes.php:437) in /home/storm/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896

Comment: updated the code. as i dont use WordPress i cant test it, but the second example should work as charm